# wordpress plugin php file processing form

Tags: plugin-development, forms

i try to analyse a plugin operations , and , at some point we fill a form to be process , but i don't know by who the form is processed as  i have this kind of html form , so i wonder how  i can know the final php file who handle realy my form.

```
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin- 
      post.php' ) ); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="check_imported">
        <input type="hidden" name="importer" value="<?php echo esc_attr( 
        $uid ); ?>">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'check_imported', 'check_imported', false ); 
          ?>
        <table class="import">
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form action is the *file* that handles the form, which you can see is the admin-post.php file in your WordPress installation.

However what you are really looking for is the *hook* that handles the form.

Basically, the form is getting submitted to admin-post.php, which then uses the "action" value in your form to determine what hook to trigger; in other words, what code to run. This is a common WordPress paradigm.

The hook name is generated in this format:

`admin_post_{{action}}` for logged in users, and
`admin_post_nopriv_{{action}}` for non-logged in users

In your case the action is set to "check_imported". So if you are trying to find code that is already handling these, do a search in your theme/plugins for "admin_post_check_imported" and/or "admin_post_nopriv_check_imported".

They would be written as an add_action call, connecting the hook name to some other function, like:

`add_action( 'admin_post_check_imported', 'some_function_name');`

So you would then look for the function named, "some_function_name", for the actual code.